# Can I use Def function in SQL query

Tags: sql, function

I want to return the SQL output refers on the condition that set in Def function. Will this work at below? or is there any anther method that i can create array and use it conditions for the return?

```
Def condition(x)
x = ['USA','China','Germany']
SELECT * from dataset1 Where country IN x
```

Comment: What?  What database?

Comment: What happens when you try it?